# React SSR and local docker?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, server-side-rendering

I have found this example app https://github.com/aws-samples/react-ssr-lambda but what I need to do is run it locally under docker using `SAM CLI`. Wondering if this is possible and all that would have to be done is add a .yaml with the correct config?

Or is there a `react-ssr` template for `sam cli` that I just haven't happened across yet that could be helpful? Also want to use `Typescript` which would be nice.

I could use the project I found with `AWS CDK` but can't see any docker local stuff in the documentation, so would probably rather convert it to use `SAM CLI` if possible since that is what we use on our `CI/CD`